# Почему MySql не видит столбец при обращении через точку?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Я осуществляю запрос через PDO.
Запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM ridergps2_orders FULL JOIN ridergps2_ms_agents 
ON ridergps2_orders.id = ridergps2_ms_agets.order_id
AND ridergps2_orders.amocrm_id = -1
```

Однако получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ridergps2_orders.id' in 'on clause'
```

Пробовал так заключать в кавычки запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `ridergps2_orders` FULL JOIN `ridergps2_ms_agents` 
ON `ridergps2_orders.id` = `ridergps2_ms_agets.order_id`
AND `ridergps2_orders.amocrm_id` = -1
```

И так:

```
SELECT * FROM `ridergps2_orders` FULL JOIN `ridergps2_ms_agents` 
ON `ridergps2_orders`.`id` = `ridergps2_ms_agets`.`order_id`
AND `ridergps2_orders`.`amocrm_id` = -1
```

Но не помогает, ошибка так же. Столбец существует, 2 раза перепроверял.

Comment: Не существует оператора `FULL JOIN` в mysql... судя по условию вполне подойдёт, тот же, `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, нет оператора FULL JOIN в MySql 5.7 и в названии таблицы была опечатка.